# how to fix first 3 columns in table using css

Tags: jquery, css, plugins

How to make first 3 columns fix in a Html table. how to make headers fix and left 3 columns fix in the following code.. please kindly check the updated link`[1]: https://plnkr.co/edit/hwwknEpLz5CqcC8I5i1J?p=preview`

Comment: Please read [ask] and don't try to bypass the message that told you to include relevant code in the question. We shouldn't have to go off site to review the basics of your issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "fix"? Do you mean make them fixed width?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this js lib to freeze the column and header. It is working fine in my project.
http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/